# Android R Id to type File

Tags: android, audio, playback, slowdown

I'm making an app that must slow down the playback of audio files.  The audio files' ids are in an int[] array (like R.raw.one, R.raw.two).  Here's my problem, I'm trying to iterate through this array, pick out an id to get the audio file, and put it in a FileInputStream so I can eventually read it to an AudioTrack and slow the audio down.  The problem is that FileInputStream only takes File type, not int (the ID is hexadecimal).

I can't think of another way to do this.  Can I slow down playback with MediaPlayer?  Because that would be way easier.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.one);
```

will return an input stream of the file. not that [getResources](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29) is a context method.